# Doing a backup with mysqldump and drop it on another server (Bash)

Tags: mysql, backup, bash, shell

I'm using a cron job to do backups hourly and now, I want to drop those backups on another server by default.

My script is the following:

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p db_password db_name| gzip > /current/path/for/backups/backup_$(date).sql.gz
```

What can I do to change the current path for a new path on another server?

Comment: Depending on your use case it may be easier to just set up [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) between the 2 database servers and create your hourly backups on the slave instead of the master (which would have the added benefit of backups not locking tables on the master). This won't work if you want to use any statements on the slave the update/change the database since that would break replication.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shared folder on destination and mount it on mysql server then give the destination path in the script to that mounted folder.  This should work.  Alternatively you can initiate a scp connection to copy the conent to destination server.

Comment: Correct.  I'd suggest NFS for the shared storage, since it can be easily mounted as a local directory.

Comment: scp or ssh command?

Comment: `scp /path/sourcefile user@server:/path/destinationfile`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the file at your local machine, you can try something like this:

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p db_password db_name| ssh user@example.com "cat > /path/to/dump.sql"
```

To compress the file before transfer (`ssh` will also try to compress it's traffic):

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p db_password db_name| gzip  | ssh user@example.com "cat > /path/to/dump.sql.gz"
```

It might be that on your remote system, `cat` will automatically unzip the stream if you pipe it into a file named `.gz`. In that case, just use another suffix.

Comment: The file will be compressed with this command?

Comment: @AlejandroAraujo  See my edit.

Comment: Don't give execution access to a server that only needs read/write access to a certain destination. Downvote for security madness.

Comment: @moebius_eye: If this is a "security madness" or not depends on a lot of factors. Stop spreading FUD.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it most of the time : bakup, copy to another server and then remove it from the source

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p db_password db_name| gzip > /current/path/for/backups/backup_$(date).sql.gz;

#Searching, moving to other server and deleting backup files from source.
cd /current/path/for/backups/backup_$(date).sql.gz;
for f in *.gz
do
    scp -pr $f hostnameofotherserver:/destination/path/mysql/backup
    wait
    echo "Removing $f..."
    rm -f $f
done
```

For reference on **SSH key setup** ( without a password every time )

http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/07/mysql-daily-backup-and-transfer-to-other-server/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-off-site-backup-of-your-site-with-rsync-on-centos-6

Comment: I'm not a master with bash but where you put the another server password for login? You can't move the file just like that or yes?

Comment: You can. You need to setup SSH, try that with a dummy database. The [script in this link](http://andycroll.com/development/backing-up-mysql-databases-remotely-using-cron-and-ssh/) will give you the complete information